# Ignore output parameters in C

Tags: c, function

I have a function which returns some value and some parameters:

```
uint8 myFunction(uint8* param1);

uint8 myFunction(uint8* param1)
{
    *param1 = 3;

    return 1;
}
```

Later in my code I would like to use the function once with returning a value like:

```
uint8 a;
uint8 b;

a = myFunction(b);

...
...
```

and once with just ignoring the parameter, like:

```
a = myFunction(void);
```

How to do this in C?

Comment: Unfortunately, default parameters is not a feature offered by C. You can have a wrapper on `myFunction` which takes no arguments, or you can send a special parameter which you can check and ignore inside `myFunction`.

Comment: It would be simpler to just have two functions. The suggestion of using an input parameter as sentinel value for different behaviour  makes the code harder to read and optimize .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend adding a NULL check before dereferencing `param1` - that would be wise anyway. Then you can just pass NULL where you want to ignore it.

```
uint8 myFunction(uint8* param1)
{
    if (param1 != NULL)
    {
        *param1 = 3;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

calling code can then just pass `NULL`:

```
a = myFunction(NULL);
```

Of course, it would be good to clearly document this behavior.